# RecyclerView GridLayoutManager first row bigger hight than other rows

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using simple `RecyclerView` - `GridLayoutManager` and the first row is bigger size than others.

**This is the layout with the `RecyclerView`:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/single_gallery_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is the creation of `gridLayoutManager`:**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mParentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fra_gallery_single, null);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) mParentView.findViewById(R.id.single_gallery_list);

    mAdapter = new SingleGalleryAdapter(getActivity(), ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSelectedGalleryData().getPhotos());

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mRecyclerView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.main_background_color));
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new AppItemDecorator(3, 7));

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3));

    return mParentView;
}
```

Here is how my item layout look like:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/single_item_img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/img_gallery_1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have very simple adapter.
Here is picture how my screen look like:

[image]

Any suggestions why my first row is bigger than others?

Answer (score 0):

I find out why this is happening:

I'm loading needed data for every item this way:

This is my information object.

```
public class PhotoItemData {

@Attribute
private String url;

public int getDrawableId(Context context){
    return context.getResources().getIdentifier(url, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
}
}
```

This is my adapter code, where i take the data for every item

```
   @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SingleGalleryViewHolder holder, int position) {
        PhotoItemData photoItemData = mData.get(position);

 holder.singleItemImg.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, photoItemData.getDrawableId(mContext)));
}
```

And every time my first pic is with bigger size than the others.
I should find a way to load the first pic with proper size.

If i change the code like this:

```
holder.singleItemImg.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.thumb_gallery_3));
```

works fine.

Comment: I fix this with adding exact height size of the ImageView:

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/single_item_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

</LinearLayout>